# WKWebView not rendering correctly in iOS 10

Tags: wkwebview, ios10

I have WKWebView inside the UITableViewCell. The web view load request and then after finished loading, I'll resize the web view height to be equal to its content height, then adjust table view cell height to fit accordingly.

What happened was the web view only displays the area that fit the screen size. When I scroll down, everything is white. But I see that the web view rendered with correct height, tap and hold on the white area on the web view still see selection. Zooming with pinch makes the web view area that displaying on the screen visible, but other areas sometimes become white.

It works fine on iOS 8 and 9. I have created a sample project to demonstrate this behaviour here:
https://github.com/pawin/strange-wkwebview

Open Radar:
https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4944718286815232

#### Update: This issue is resolved in iOS11

Comment: Did you solve it?  i have the same problem

Comment: I have just noticed this occurs when image in the content

Comment: I haven't solved it yet, you saying if the website has only text, it works normally?

Comment: yes, if the website only text it works

Comment: I tried with text only website, doesn't work as well. :(

Comment: I have the same problem, so I replaced the tableView by collectionView, and everything works fine. Hope there are someone can figure out what's wrong with tableViewCell and WKWebView.

Comment: Could you share how you got the proper webview content size? I currently always get an inaccurate height.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to force the `WKWebView` to layout while your `UITableView` scrolls.

```
// in the UITableViewDelegate
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if let tableView = scrollView as? UITableView {
        for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
            guard let cell = cell as? MyCustomCellClass else { continue }
            cell.webView?.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Thank you! works for me. It looks like wkwebview doesn’t refresh the content out of the screen somehow. Anyway I am creating Apple other ticket so perhaps will be added next beta. It still fails in 10.1 beta 5.

Comment: Wasn't it be better to run this code in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating delegate method?

Comment: I was struggling to find this solution from last many days! Good job!

Comment: Brilliant!! Dealing with webview is always pain in the ass.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem - add a WKWebView to a UITableViewCell, and I solved this problem by these steps:

1.Create a UITextView instance and add it to UITableView's superview(UIViewControllew.view)

2.implement codes in *scrollViewDidScroll* like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self.xxtextView becomeFirstResponder];
    [self.xxtextView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

These codes may cause increased cpu performance overhead, you can fix it by some way such us use a temp variable as threshold value.

I don't think this is a perfect solve method, but it works for me.

---

Eventually I realized that textview becomeFirstResponder just led the webview layout again, so you can just fix it like this:

```
CGFloat tempOffset = 0;

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (!tempOffset || ABS(scrollView.contentOffset.y - tempOffset) > ScreenHeight/2)
    {
        [self.wkWebView setNeedsLayout];
        tempOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    func reloadWKWebViewIfNeeded() {
    for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells {
        guard let webviewCell = cell as? WebviewCell else { continue }

        // guard cell height > screen height

        webviewCell.webview.reload()
    }
}

override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    guard !decelerate else { return }

    self.reloadWKWebViewIfNeeded()
}

override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.reloadWKWebViewIfNeeded()
}
```

Not the best solution though, but at least user can see the rest of the content

Answer (score 0):

Im also have uitableview with cell with wkWebView. And i stack with same problem. But timely you can fix this with this code. By performance do not worry. I tested this solution on iphone 5s and it was taken 10-15% CPU only when you scrolling uitableView with visible web cell.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   //TODO: Remove this fix when WKWebView will fixed
   if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)) as? WKWebViewCell {
      // Here we take our cell
      cell.wkWebView?.setNeedsLayout() 
      // here is "magic" (where wkWebView it is WKWebView, which was 
      // previously added on cell)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In objective-C this is how I solve the problem.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSArray * visibleCell = [self.tableView visibleCells];

    for (CustomUITableViewCell * cell in visibleCell) {
        if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomUITableViewCell class]]) {
            [cell.wkWebView setNeedsLayout];
        }
    }
}
```

That code will collect all visible cell and do the `setNeedsLayout` in fast enumeration during user scroll.