# iOS10 WKWebview - evaluateJavaScript("document.height") return nil

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, wkwebview

In my app, I need to get the height of a webpage in a `WKWebView`. So I use the code below.

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript(("document.height"), completionHandler: { contentHeight,error in
    print(contentHeight)
})
```

Until iOS 9, this returns the webpage height correctly. But in iOS 10, `contentHeight` is always `nil`.

I've set

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
```

and the web view is in a `UITableViewCell`.

The height of `webView` and of the `UITableViewCell` are variable. There's a top and bottom constraint on the web view to fit to the cell.

When I get the webpage height, I want it to be reflected in the cell's height.

Comment: I'm facing this problem as well, my current workaround is to use its contentSize.height, for now.

Answer (score 9):

try this:

```
let javascriptString = "" +
            "var body = document.body;" +
            "var html = document.documentElement;" +
            "Math.max(" +
            "   body.scrollHeight," +
            "   body.offsetHeight," +
            "   html.clientHeight," +
            "   html.offsetHeight" +
        ");"

    webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascriptString) { (result, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if let result = result, let height = JSON(result).int {
                self.htmlContentHeight = CGFloat(height)
                self.resetContentCell()
            }
        }
    }
```

PS. WKWebiew rendering problem:
[WKWebView not rendering correctly in iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549103/wkwebview-not-render-correctly-in-ios-10)

Comment: Thank you for reply! I can get height of webpage! But if I set WKWebview.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false , I can't get height. Do you know some ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem. Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39556938

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript(("document.body.offsetHeight"), completionHandler:^(id _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@">>>%@",result);
})
```