# WKWebview not fully loaded in iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, ios10, wkwebview

I got the problem that I'm loading a local html file in a WKWebview.
My procedure is working for iOS 8, 9, 11 but not for 10.3. There is just white space in the middle of the text.

I'm creating my WKWebview like this:

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration();
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: self.webViewHeight);
infoWebView = WKWebView(frame: frame, configuration: webConfiguration);
infoWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
infoWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
infoWebView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false;
infoWebView.clipsToBounds = false;
infoWebView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false
infoWebView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
infoWebView.sizeToFit()
```

The loading of my html file is done by the following code:

```
if let availableUrl = url {
                let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: availableUrl)
                infoWebView.load(urlRequest)
            }
```

Do you have an idea why it's working for iOS 8,9,11 but not for iOS 10.3?
Can somebody reproduce this problem?

Kind regards and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had my wkwebview in a table view I had to override scrollViewDidScroll from UITableViewDelegate.

this code from [WKWebView not rendering correctly in iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549103/wkwebview-not-rendering-correctly-in-ios-10) did the trick for me:

```
// in the UITableViewDelegate
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if let tableView = scrollView as? UITableView {
        for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
            guard let cell = cell as? MyCustomCellClass else { continue }
            cell.webView?.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}
```